# svn log on specific lines in a file

Tags: svn

Let's say a given set of lines were modified in a file, I want to find the SVN revision at which they were modified. Currently I just have to keep picking through the log and finding where it was last added manually, is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

`svn blame myFile` gives you the revision-number and author of each line

**edit:** Take a look at [this document](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.blame). You can also add some options to the command. For instance:

- --revision (-r)
- --incremental

Comment: Good utility however it doesn't concern how to search on which line was edited across revisions.

Comment: ok, then try to mix `svn log` and `svn diff`. At first you call `log` on your file to get all relevant revision-numbers and then call `diff` on each relevant revision. example for revision-number 5: `svn diff -r 4:5 myFile` which results in all changes made by the commit in rev5 in myFile. The creation of a shell-script will be a task for homework. Does this answer your question or do I miss sth?